# This Piece of code still does not update excel

Tags: vba, csv, excel

I would like to copy data from a csv file into an excel worksheet. There are 11 csv files. 
So far I have this (it is a modified version from a previous post):

```
Sub importData()   
  Dim filenum(0 To 10) As Long
  filenum(0) = 052
  filenum(1) = 060
  filenum(2) = 064
  filenum(3) = 068
  filenum(4) = 070
  filenum(5) = 072
  filenum(6) = 074
  filenum(7) = 076
  filenum(8) = 178
  filenum(9) = 180
  filenum(10) = 182

  Dim sh1 As Worksheet
  On Error GoTo my_handler

  For lngPosition = LBound(filenum) To UBound(filenum)
    Workbooks.Add(filenum(lngPosition) & ".csv").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("30_graphs_w_Macro.xlsm").Activate
    Set sh1 = Worksheets(filenum(lngPosition))
    'sh1.Activate
    sh1.Range("A69").Paste
    Range("A69").Select

  Next lngPositionlngPositionlngPosition

my_handler:
  MsgBox "All done."
  Exit Sub
End Sub
```

I am not too sure why it still does not update the excel file with the data from the csv.